# Xamarin Forms transparent button hides image

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Frame containing an Image and a Button but even though the background colour for the button is set to transparent it still hides the image behind it and I've been unable to figure why this is so. Removing the button makes the image appear just fine.

```
    <Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Frame x:Name="SettingsFrame" CornerRadius="42" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="#aa2129" Padding="0">
            <Image Source="whitecog.PNG" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Scale="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="SettingsButton" Clicked="OnSettingsClick"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                    BorderWidth="1"  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderRadius="0"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: A frame can only have a single child - I often use a Grid to superimpose views on each other (using same row/column).

Comment: Ah I see! Makes sense

Comment: FWIW if your goal is to create a clickable image then I'd add a TapGestureRecognizer to the GestureRecognizers on the image

Comment: Suppose so, depends though. I need to change between two images and off the top of my head it was easiest to change visibility of the two images when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to simply toggle between two images - you can extend `Grid` to use `TapGestureRecognizer` (I have implemented this in C#, but you can do the same in XAML too).

```
public class ToggleImage : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ToggledSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ToggledSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Image), default(ImageSource), propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty OriginalSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("OriginalSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Image), default(ImageSource), propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsToggled", typeof(bool), typeof(Image), false, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);

    private Image _originalImage;
    private Image _toggledImage;

    public ToggleImage()
    {
        var tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapRecognizer.Command = new Command(() => IsToggled = !IsToggled);
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer);

        _originalImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
        _toggledImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };

        Children.Add(_originalImage);
        Children.Add(_toggledImage);
    }

    static void OnValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var ctrl = bindable as ToggleImage;
        if (ctrl == null)
            return;

        ctrl.OnValueChanged();
    }

    void OnValueChanged()
    {
        _originalImage.Source = OrginalSource;
        _toggledImage.Source = ToggledSource;

        _toggledImage.IsVisible = IsToggled;
        _originalImage.IsVisible = !IsToggled;
    }

    public bool IsToggled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource ToggledSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ToggledSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggledSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource OrginalSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(OriginalSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OriginalSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
<Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2">
  <Frame x:Name="SettingsFrame" CornerRadius="42" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="#aa2129" Padding="0">
      <local:ToggleImage IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled}" OriginalSource="image1.png" ToggledSource="image2.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Scale="1"/>
  </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I would totally recommend this solution